# Determining which activity is calling AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Is there a way to find out which activity is calling `AsyncTask`? I have two activities which are calling it and I want to do different stuff in `onPostExecute()`, depending on which activity is calling it.

Something like that:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    //do some stuff with result
    if (callingActivity == mainActivity) {
        //do something
    } else {
        //do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a constructor to your `AsyncTask` subclass and pass in some identifier of what the creator was.

Comment: Oh my God, I feel ashamed for not figuring that on my own. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We always have ***instanceof*** for the rescue. Capture the callingActivity while creating AsyncTask and use it in onPostExecute.

For example,

There are two Activities ActivityA and ActivityB. You can check in onPostExecute like

```
class AsyncTask<..,..,..> {

  private Activity a;

  public AsyncTask(Activity a) {
    this.a = a;
  }

  protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    //do some stuff with result
    if (a instanceof ActivityA) {
        //do something
    } else if (a instanceof ActivityB) {
        //do something else
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: You're risking of leaking the `Activity` by holding a strong reference to it in the `AsyncTask`.

Answer (score 1):

Just have your Activities subclass your `CommonAsyncTask`, overriding `onPostExecute()`:

```
new CommonAsyncTask() {
  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // Execute the common code in `CommonAsyncTask`
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    // Now execute the code unique to this activity
  }
};
```